# Python unions with typevars

Tags: python, python-typing

```py
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar("T")
v = t.Union[int , T]

a: v = "g"
t.reveal_type(a)   # Unknown | int
```

The above code passes the Pylance checks, however...it seems *illogical*. Did I discovered another "feature" of Pylance OR the code above really **is** correct and has some real-world applications?

For what I understand, in python's type-hints TypeVars need to be *constrained*, or in another words, be used twice in a function or class declaration.

Comment: mypy reports no errors either. Weird.

Comment: a free typevar (as in `v` in `a: v`) just means `object`, and `"g"` is an `object`. I don't know why pylance shows `Unknown`. It should fail for `a: v[int]`

Comment: Mypy infers T as Any and appropriately errors out on both the missing type parameter and inferred Any if it’s not run with lenient flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v` is a [`Generic` `TypeAlias`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-type-aliases). Your declaration of `a` as a `v` is missing its type argument. `pyright` can actually notify you of this mistake if you enable `reportMissingTypeArgument` in your `settings.json`. I use the following modified [pyright diagnostic rules](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/configuration?id=diagnostic-rule-defaults):

```json
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportMissingTypeArgument": "warning",
        "reportGeneralTypeIssues": "error"
    },
```

Correctly, your declaration should be:

```py
a: v[str] = "g"
reveal_type(a)  # Type of "a" is "Literal['g']"
```

[`TypeVar`s must be bound to a valid scope](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/type-concepts-advanced.md#type-variable-scoping) (as a function parameter, which can then also be re-used around a `Generic` class). They are not bound otherwise, and in the declaration of an instance of `Generic` type, you should provide a type argument, for example:

```py
from typing import List

places: List[str] = []
places.append("New York")
```